# Find unique elements in a list in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I am working on a project with OCaml and there are some problems regarding to arrays that I am not sure with. I am not allowed to use the List module, so please give me some idea or suggestion with my works.

First, I already implemented a function `'a list -> 'a list` called `uniq` that return a list of the uniq elements in an array, for example  `uniq [5;6;5;4] => [6;5;4]`

Here is my implementation:

```
let rec uniq x =
let rec uniq_help l n = 
    match l with
        [] -> []
    |   h :: t -> uniq_help t, n if (n = h) else (h :: (uniq_help(t, n)))
match x with
    [] -> []
|   h::t -> uniq_help t, h
;;
```

I mot sure this is a correct implementation, can someone give me some suggestion or correctness?

Comment: The code as given doesn't compile for me.  It looks like you're missing an `in` somewhere.  The way to define a local symbol like `uniq_help` is `let local = <localdef> in <expr-using-local>`.

Comment: They're not Arrays in OCaml, they're lists.  Arrays imply mutable state, which isn't the way lists in ocaml work without explicitly using something from the Array module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You functions are syntactically incorrect for various reasons:

- `uniq_help` takes two elements so you have to invoke it using `uniq_help t n`, not `uniq_help(t, n)` and the like.
- an `if/else` expression should have the form of `if cond then expr1 else expr2`.
- to use `uniq_help` locally in `uniq`, you need an `in` keyword.

After fixing syntax errors, your function looks like:

```
let rec uniq x =
  let rec uniq_help l n = 
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> if n = h then uniq_help t n else h::(uniq_help t n) in
  match x with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> uniq_help t h
```

However, to be sure that each element is unique in the list, you have to check uniqueness for all of its elements. One quick fix could be:

```
let rec uniq x =
     (* uniq_help is the same as above *)
     match x with
     | [] -> []
     | h::t -> h::(uniq_help (uniq t) h)
```

Comment: For my understanding, the unip_help is adding the last occurrence of the element in the list, but the last occurrence will also be added multiple times in the list!!!